# Is it possible to complete this challenge in every map?

Tags: splinter-cell-conviction

In Tom Clancy's Splinter Cell: Conviction, one of the most difficult challenges that can be devised is to get to the end of a Deniable Ops map (by subduing all of the enemies) with these restrictions:

- Pistol only
- No gadgets
- Hand-to-hand kills only
- One attempt (no retries, restart from lobby)
- Infiltration
- Realistic difficulty

I haven't tried it on every map, so I'm wondering: Is there any map where it's physically impossible to complete it with these restrictions? I can't imagine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got the multiple challenges mixed up because individually I did them, once with pistol only and once with hand to hand only and undetected, so yes it is possible but requires a lot of patience, by the way the gadgets are not really that helpful in deniable ops, any explosion would count as a detection I couldn't even use a flash bang, as for the remote camera and its distraction it only seems to change the guards sweeping patterns and they end up behaving randomly increasing the odds of getting caught.